# Lebesgue measure of Cantor type set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

I'm learning about *Measure Theory* and need some help with this problem:

> Let $0 < \alpha < 1$. We construct a set $C_\alpha$ (Cantor type) as follows: In the first step we remove from the interval $[0, 1]$ a "middle" open interval of length $(1 - \alpha)3^{-1}$. In the nth step we remove $2^{n-1}$ open intervals of length $(1 - \alpha)3^{-n}$. Find the *Lebesgue measure* of $C_\alpha$.

**My work and thoughts:**

If we remove the set $C_\alpha$ from the close interval $[0, 1]$ we are left with the union of pairwise disjoint intervals. In more traditionally formulaic notation, we can write:

$$[0, 1] \setminus C_\alpha = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3 \cup \ldots$$

Therefore, taking the *Lebesgue measure* on both side of the preivous equality we get:

$$\mu \left([0, 1] \setminus C_\alpha \right) = \mu \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} E_n \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mu(E_n).$$

---

I need to find a way to express $\mu(E_n)$ and calculate the above series. If I can do so then the result is immediate since:

$$\mu(C_\alpha) = \mu([0, 1]) - \mu([0, 1]\setminus C_\alpha)$$

where $\mu([0, 1]) = 1$.

Comment: What's your $C_\alpha$? The remaining part? If not misunderstanding I think $\mu(E_n)$ is trivially $\frac12(1-\alpha)(2/3)^n$.

Comment: Since $C_\alpha$ is a Cantor type set I made the assumption that it is the remaining part. The problem doesn't say anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the way you construct $C_\alpha$, if you denote by $E_n$ (hopefully I'm not misinterpreting it) the removed part during the $n$th step, then clearly
$$\mu(E_n)=\frac12(1-\alpha)\left(\frac23\right)^n$$
Hence 
$$\mu(C_\alpha)=\mu([0,1]\setminus\cup E_n)=1-\sum\mu(E_n)=1-(1-\alpha)=\alpha$$

Comment: You are correct about the expression of $\mu(E_n)$. Taking the infinite sum it just comes down to calculating the geometric series. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @VonKar you are welcome.

Comment: Cantor set Not countable!!